# Creating a "redacted" / "black-out" style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a CSS style that will let my authors write markup like this:

```
On <span class="redacted">September, 10 2011</span> the special operations agent, 
<span class="redacted">John Smith</span>, on orders from his commanding 
officer, <span class="redacted">Captain Kirk</span>, terminated the well known 
terrorist <span class="redacted">Fred Flinstone</span>.
```

I currently have a style like this that does the job in a very simple low-tech way:

```
span.redacted {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

One requirement is that I *want* viewers to be able to highlight the text and see the real content "behind".  So just using an image will not work.

Instead of my current scheme of just changing the text & background colors, I want the "black-out" to look like it was really applied by a felt-tip pen. With ragged edges and stuff.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?  I really want to keep my XHMTL as pure as possible and put as much of this into CSS as I can.

[EDIT: Examples of redacted text]

This Wikipedia article provides several examples of real redacted text.  The first example is really rough (too rough I think).  The second shows an excessive amount of redaction, but you can see that the 'marker' is not straight/clean.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization_(classified_information)

I found this example as well:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_mJPzxRaCL64/S4X6Zn0MPKI/AAAAAAAAJdw/vX4MYNdUyIk/s400/ishot-2064.jpg

Comment: How about using `<del> ... </del>` rather than `<span class="redacted"> ... </span>` to keep your XHTML semantic?

Comment: @SinanÜnür, a great suggestion; semantically makes sense. But doesn't help with the formatting.

Comment: That's why it is in a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the effect you're after, but I just sort of mixed up a bunch of subtle styles to make it looks like a marker had crossed out the words, slightly "imperfect" looking:

Demo (for Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/vzC96/2/

You'll have to translate this into something cross-browser:

```
.redacted {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -moz-transform: rotate(.8deg) skewx(-12deg);
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 0 2px #444;
    border:1px dotted #555;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, #000, #222);
}

/* Add a few more selectors with slightly varying styles */
.redacted:first-child {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-.8deg);
}
.redacted:first-child + .redacted {
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
}

/* "Highlighter" effect */
.redacted::-moz-selection {
    background:#e6ff3f;
}
```

It does skew the text itself as well, but it's normally hidden so that might not matter to you.

The `white-space:nowrap;` is what will keep the spans from breaking (going to a new line).

If you want to go the image route, and use a single image, you can take advantage of CSS3's `background-size` and stretch it across the entire span.

Comment: +1: This is an awesome workaround that's a really novel concept, and (in my opinion) definitely fits the requirement.

Comment: Awesome! This might just work.  I'll have to go dig into how to make it work cross-platform.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas on how to use images (without stretching a single image)?

Comment: @tig: Add an example image to your post and someone might have an idea of how to do it. We might be imagining something different than what you have in mind.

Answer (score 22):

If you are just doing it for fun in a forum or some text in your page you could just use the Unicode Character 'FULL BLOCK' (U+2588)  █ ...and then just copy and paste it into a sentence ████████ to look like redacted material.

If that's helps you.

Comment: Here's the actual HTML decimal Entity code for the 'full block' character - which can put directly into a webpage: &#9608;

Comment: But the asker "want[s] viewers to be able to highlight the text and see the real content behind".

Answer (score 5):

Set a background image (tileable) on the element using `background-image: url('location-of-the-image.png');` that looks like a felt-tip pen.

Comment: I don't understand how a single tilealbe (that's not a word!) image can represent all 4 sides of a felt-top pen mark of variable length. I am thinking I need at least 3 images (left, middle, center) where middle can be repeated depending on the span. Also, what about word breaks across lines?

Comment: @tig: Split them up. As for the 4 sides, you should use `:before` and `:after` for the elements beside, and the tileable image can have ragged edges on the top and bottom. Reasonably cross-browser. *The only thing you will ever get to do what you want is a hack.*

Comment: Tilealbe is definitely not a word, no.

Comment: Not an English word anyway. Might be in Gaelic.